# Shell within one Shell (Prism wpf Application )

Tags: wpf, prism, tabcontrol, .net-framework-version

I have been looking for source code in which we have one shell that contains multiple shells in tabitems in wpf Application(using Prism).

I have created  application in which  we have some icon of application and when i click on one particular icon that will load my module and module shell should be open in new tabitem in the same window.(this is my idea , any idea how would i implement this )

Comment: What about this documentation: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Composing-the-UI.html ?

Comment: It seems a bit strange that you would you want another shell rather than a region.

Comment: Yes Including shell within shell is a challange

Comment: Why not a shell with a tab control with regions? Just for the sake of it being a challenge?

Comment: when my application run it show multiple modules (in the form of icon)so when i click on module it should be loaded and shell should open in new tabitem in same window by hiding the main page(that displays icon). this is a situation